# HTML removing button side inlines, instead of the whole border lines

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style a `<button>` by removing the sides of the `border` and keeping **the top and the bottom line intact**. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Where is the code you have so far? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove all borders, only define the top and bottom border:

```css
button {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #111111;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #111111;

  /* For styling purposes */
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button>button</button>
```